# How to implement a short-circuited "and" macro in Common Lisp?

Tags: macros, common-lisp, short-circuiting

Assume that the macro would take the boolean types `a` and `b` . If `a` is `nil`, then the macro should return `nil` (without ever evaluating `b`), otherwise it returns `b`. How do you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really depends on what you *can* use.
E.g., is `or` available? `if`? `cond`?

Here is one example:

```
(defmacro and (a b)
  `(if ,a ,b nil)
```

EDIT. In response to a comment, `or` is more complicated because we have to avoid double evaluation:

```
(defmacro or (a b)
  (let ((v (gensym "OR")))
    `(let ((,v ,a))
       (if ,v ,v ,b))))
```

Comment: It's an old exam question and it doesn't specify that I'm not allowed to use anything, so I guess your solution is allowed. I am just surprised this is so short. Would an `or` be equally short or does that require us to use `gensym`?

Comment: @Sid Note two things:  these implementations take advantage of the fact that there are other operators available (`if`) that have very related semantics (e.g., delayed evaluation).  A more general approach uses lambda expressions and function calls to delay evaluation.  It also works with any number of arguments (just like the `and` and `or` in the language), where as the implementation in this answer doesn't.  (It could be easily added, but it would make the implementation more complicated.)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, there's **conditional** execution and **deferred** execution. The special operator `if` does the former, using closures to execute code later is a way to implement the latter. But they're orthogonal concepts. Also, a recurring `or` macro (or even the common lisp equivalent without assertions) is not that much more complicated: `(defmacro or (&rest args) (if (null args) nil (if (null (rest args)) (first args) (let ((v (gensym "OR"))) ``(let ((,v ,(first args))) (if ,v ,v (or ,@(rest args))))))))`. I find the use of closures much more convoluted **in this case**.

Answer (score 3):

[sds's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29472221/1281433) is nice and concise, but it has two limitations:

1. It only works with two arguments, whereas the built in **and** and **or** take any number of arguments.  It's not too hard to update the solution to take any number of arguments, but it would be a bit more complicated.
2. More importantly, it's based very directly in terms of delayed operations that are already present in the language.  I.e., it takes advantage of the fact that **if** doesn't evaluate the **then** or **else** parts until it has first evaluated the condition.

It might be a good exercise, then, to note that when a macro needs to delay evaluation of some forms, it's often the *simplest* strategy (in terms of implementation, but not necessarily the most efficient) to use a macro that expands to a function call that takes a function.  For instance, a naive implementation of **with-open-file** might be:

```
(defun %call-with-open-file (pathname function)
  (funcall function (open pathname)))

(defmacro my-with-open-file ((var pathname) &body body)
  `(%call-with-open-file
    ,pathname
    (lambda (,var)
      ,@body)))
```

Using a technique like this, you can easily get a binary **and** (and **or**):

```
(defun %and (a b)
  (if (funcall a)
      (funcall b)
      nil))

(defmacro my-and (a b)
  `(%and (lambda () ,a)
         (lambda () ,b)))
```

```
CL-USER> (my-and t (print "hello"))
"hello" ; printed output
"hello" ; return value
CL-USER> (my-and nil (print "hello"))
NIL
```

**or** is similar:

```
(defun %or (a b)
  (let ((aa (funcall a)))
    (if aa
        aa
        (funcall b))))

(defmacro my-or (a b)
  `(%or (lambda () ,a)
        (lambda () ,b)))
```

To handle the n-ary case (since **and** and **or** actually take any number of arguments), you could write a function that takes a list of lambda functions and calls each of them until you get to one that would short circuit (or else reaches the end).  Common Lisp actually already has functions like that:  **every** and **some**.  With this approach, you could implement **and** in terms of [**every**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_everyc.htm) by wrapping all the arguments in lambda functions:

```
(defmacro my-and (&rest args)
  `(every #'funcall
          (list ,@(mapcar #'(lambda (form)
                              `(lambda () ,form))
                          args))))
```

For instance, with this implementation,

```
(my-and (listp '()) (evenp 3) (null 'x))
```

expands to:

```
(EVERY #'FUNCALL
       (LIST (LAMBDA () (LISTP 'NIL))
             (LAMBDA () (EVENP 3))
             (LAMBDA () (NULL 'X))))
```

Since all the forms are now wrapped in lambda functions, they won't get called until **every** gets that far.

The only difference is that **and** is specially defined to return the value of the last argument if all the preceding ones are true (e.g., **(and t t 3)** returns **3**, not **t**, whereas the specific return value of **every** is not specified (except that it would be a *true* value).

With this approach, implementing **or**  (using [**some**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_everyc.htm)) is no more complicated than implementing **and**:

```
(defmacro my-or (&rest args)
  `(some #'funcall ,@(mapcar #'(lambda (form)
                                 `(lambda () ,form))
                             args)))
```

Comment: In my opinion, this is a bit too much academic just to avoid the use of `if`, which is a special operator (i.e. intrinsically part of the language) for **conditional** execution.  You described **deferred** execution, so this is *almost* an answer.  Note that `every` and `some` must eventually use some sort of `if`.  In essence, you're deferring execution in the form of closures to `every` and `some`, which will conditionally execute your closures.  There's no escaping `if`, how would you implement `every` and `some` without a direct or indirect dependency on it?

Comment: @PauloMadeira I wasn't suggesting this as an alternative implementation of the logical operators, but adding some commentary about how one can achieve as task "without ever evaluating [something]".  You're absolutely right that on a Von Neumann type machine, we're always going to need branching execution.  That said, you can still do conditionals with functions, e.g., http://pastebin.com/fPSTLHsR (a quick and dirty implementation of [Church booleans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_Booleans).  Of course, that's not how booleans actually are in Common Lisp, so it's not very

Comment: @PauloMadeira useful in that regard, but it doesn't mean that being aware of some of these kinds of techniques can't ever be helpful.  The main point of this answer is that if you need to delay evaluation, one of the most straightforward ways to do it with a macro is by wrapping a form in a lambda function.

Comment: @PauloMadeira But to show that I'm not averse to using **if** in the macro expansion, I added a binary version that does use it, but still uses lambda functions to delay the evaluation. :)